# Could not resolve host cloudsearch.amazonaws.com in Vagrant/Homestead

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using Laravel/Homestead to developing website and retrieve search result from AWS cloudsearch. Unfortunately, I got following errors that curl could not resolve host cloudsearch.amazonaws.com.

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: search-search--XXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com
```

And here's the things I know about this error.

- Curl able to resolve cloudsearch.amazonaws.com in host machine instead of virtual machine (Vagrant).
- Curl fail even though firewall is shutdown
- Traceroute fail to resolve the host also.

Here's the traceroute results

```
~$ traceroute search-XXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com
search-XXXXX.ap-northeast-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `search-XXXXX.ap-northeast-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

Comment: Are you able to curl _anything_ from your VM? If it's working from your host machine but not your VM, this sounds much more like a network configuration issue than a cloudsearch issue.

Comment: @alexroussos I am able to curl example.com, google.com from VM except cloudsearch. I know the problems is due to cloudsearch network configuration, but I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: I will be very appreciate if you guide to the next step. Thank you

Comment: Check your CloudSearch security settings to see if it's using an ip-based access policy. That's the only reason I can think of that it would reject requests from one host but not another. I'd open the query endpoint to be publicly accessible for testing and try that. Also note that it doesn't respond to pings so I'm not sure traceroute will work (I can't check bc traceroute gives me an error that my hostname is too long). Good luck!

Comment: Try adding in the https:// before the domain. I had a trouble with a Google Compute Engine where it thought the entire input was the domain. For example, instead of typing `curl mail.google.com`, type `curl https://mail.google.com`. I have never used Vagrant, but if you try to use their web SSH client (if they have one) instead of your own machine, that may help as well.